# Single Processing Unit and Multiple Users

Tags: workspaces

How can build system with Ubuntu using a single Processing Unit (Probabluly normal CPU or Intel NUC with i5) on which 5 or more users can use it simultaniously?
So there going to be one one CPU and 5 or more Moniters, Keyboards and Mouse, so every user front on each computer can do his own work..
I want to use it in a school in a village in India to teach basic things about computer and so wanted it to be cost effective..
If it is not possible with above sysyem, please suggest alternative ideas.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/106842/can-two-users-simultaneously-share-one-pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called a **multiseat configuration**.

It is definitely possible, however it requires a bit of hacking.

You might want to start here: https://wiki.debian.org/Multi_Seat_Debian_HOWTO

Or here: http://automseat.sourceforge.net/